# Ubuntu 'disappeared' on Windows 8.1 update

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8

As I have a very poor internet connection, I have only recently been able to update to Windows 8.1. Up until then I had been using a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu (13.04) where I was givent the option of which OS to use at boot. However, after updating the GRUB menu has completely disappeared. I have done some research and can find nothing about this. I am not sure whether Ubuntu has been deleted or simply the option to access it has gone. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 8.1 installer must have overwritten the MBR and thus removed Grub.

To solve this problem, use Boot Repair as follows:
boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
choose "Try Ubuntu"
connect to the Internet
open a new Terminal, then type: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

- Press ENTER.
- Then type: `sudo apt-get update`

followed by: `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

Finally type: `boot-repair`

and choose **Recommended repair**.

Reboot your PC to check if the problem persists.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

P.S. Ubuntu 13.04 has reached end-of-life and it is strongly recommended to upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am downloading Ubuntu now (this may take some time...)

Comment: Also - Is there a quicker way than downloading a whole Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade. But it still has to download a lot of stuff :)

Comment: Do-release upgrade is not quicker. it is not a download of an ISO but upgrade of the existing packages and it is much slower than installing afresh, but this is not the right question to discuss upgrade vs fresh install.